# Are Yang-Mills Fields sections of associated bundles to the orthonormal frame bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, yang-mills, classical-field-theory

Let $\pi: P \to M$ be a principal bundle and $\omega$ a connection on it. Given a section $\sigma: M \to P$ we define   Yang-Mills fields by
$$A=\sigma^*\omega$$

Now since under Lorentz transformation the Yang-Mills field  $A$ should transform like  vectors,
are this Fields also, sections of associated bundles to  $SO(1,3)$ orthonormal frame bundle ?

Answer (score 1):

The $A$ you define is a Lie-algebra valued 1-form on the base manifold $M$, and so is a local section of the cotangent bundle $T^*(M)$. Usually a physicist would make this clear by writing
$$
A= \hat \lambda_a A^a_\mu dx^\mu
$$
where $\hat \lambda_a$ is a  generator of the Lie algebra. The index $\mu$ indicates the cotangent character of the gauge field.

Comment: I know that  $A$ is Lie-algebra valued 1-form. what i am asking if it is considered as an element of the  associated  bundle of the orthonormal bundle

Comment: I think all one-forms can be considered as sections of the *dual* of the orthonormal frame bundle. Just write $A= \hat \lambda_a A^a_m {\bf e}^{*m}$ where ${\bf e}^{*m}$ is the orthonormal co-frame ${\bf e}^{*m}= e^{*m}_\mu dx^\mu$ with  $g_{\mu\nu}= \eta_{mn} e^{*m}_\mu e^{*n}_\nu$.  So, in some sense, it is associated to the $O(3,1)$ principle bundle.